# Error build an app ionic iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, build

This error occurs when I try to build an ionic app on iOS. Can somebody help me? I already try to to remove and add iOS platform, but it doesn't work.

> ERROR:::
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
>   /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Casamento_VIVO-ehnpkzwqfnsjomcotuxogsiuppoj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Casamento\
>   VIVO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Casamento\
>   VIVO.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneSignalPush.o Casamento\
>   VIVO/Plugins/onesignal-cordova-plugin/OneSignalPush.m normal x86_64
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)
>   (node:2346) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 65 for
>   command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Developer/workspace/casa-madu/app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Casamento
>   VIVO.xcworkspace,-scheme,Casamento
>   VIVO,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Developer/workspace/casa-madu/app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Developer/workspace/casa-madu/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   (node:2346) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:2346) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Please include the error as actual text and not an image, let alone a low-res one like this.

Comment: edited, error included

Comment: Maybe a [mcve] so we can see what you are trying to do.